# отправка .xlsx файлов по расписанию через телеграм бота

Tags: python, telebot

Есть задача отправить excel документ по расписанию через телеграмм бота. Вот весь код:

```
    import telebot
    import schedule
    import time
        
    API_TOKEN=TOKEN
    
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)
        
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['document'])
    def welcome(message):
        with open('D:\\sql\\exported_data.xlsx', 'rb') as f1:
            bot.send_document(message.chat.id, f1)
     
    
     schedule.every().monday.at('12:00').do(welcome)
     
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Но код не работает, подскажите пожалуйста. где искать ошибку.

Comment: Что именно не работает? Ошибка, или сам код ничего не отправляет?

Comment: У Вас бесконечный цикл `while True:`, поэтому не работает.

Answer (score 0):

get_data - метод получения данных с базы

```
def spammer():
    Spammer('123451255').get_data()

def start_spam():
    schedule.every(60).seconds.do(spammer)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
```

посмотрите в сторону библиотеки schedule, у меня была задача отпрвлять данные в телеграм групу раз в какоето время.